# Opera load time

Tags: opera

UPDATE: I'm not sure how or why, but disabling HW acceleration, restarting and then re-enabling HW acceleration seems to have made a huge difference.

Running Ubuntu 22.04.
If I load opera from Activities  (super + a shortcut), then it takes a long time to load. (I have not timed this and in fact I don't even know how to do so.)
If I open a terminal and type "opera", it loads almost immediately.
Why is this the case and how might I remedy it?

opening opera from Activities menu yields:
https://pastebin.com/m0BCJtnQ

opening opera from terminal yields:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Dec  4 10:50:18 moonface systemd[1]: Stopped Bumblebee C Daemon.
Dec  4 10:50:18 moonface systemd[1]: Started Bumblebee C Daemon.
Dec  4 10:50:18 moonface bumblebeed[138977]: [98454.186574] [ERROR]No discrete video card found, quitting
Dec  4 10:50:18 moonface systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec  4 10:50:18 moonface systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec  4 10:50:23 moonface systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-759c42f721e89be363aac97cfdec28c2ae8fb9d997a61f80123397bc3cf3d05d-runc.q0hLTE.mount: Succeeded.
Dec  4 10:50:32 moonface kernel: [98467.667729] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169032.626:596): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139001 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=330 compat=0 ip=0x7f6db21604e7 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:50:33 moonface kernel: [98468.983293] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169033.942:597): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139014 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=330 compat=0 ip=0x7f6db21604e7 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:50:55 moonface opera_opera.desktop[137625]: [137625:137625:1204/105055.952617:ERROR:CONSOLE(547)] "Uncaught (in promise) Error", source: chrome-extension://ebongfbmlegepmkkdjlnlmdcmckedlal/touch_communication.js (547)
Dec  4 10:50:58 moonface systemd[3146]: snap.opera.opera.960106bd-0d4f-4d89-aab0-9b2ef0dc140d.scope: Succeeded.
Dec  4 10:51:07 moonface wpa_supplicant[1054]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
Dec  4 10:51:08 moonface systemd[3146]: Started snap.opera.opera.41c7f244-a617-4186-91ca-d5ce4ed9b112.scope.
Dec  4 10:51:08 moonface dbus-daemon[3163]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/freedesktop/secrets" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.secrets" pid=139230 label="snap.opera.opera" peer_pid=3158 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.159350] audit: type=1107 audit(1670169069.118:598): pid=1016 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=139166 label="snap.opera.opera" peer_pid=1506 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.159350]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782397] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:599): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782760] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:600): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782767] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:601): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782772] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:602): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782776] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:603): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782781] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:604): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782820] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:605): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782840] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:606): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:09 moonface kernel: [98504.782909] audit: type=1326 audit(1670169069.742:607): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=139263 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/210/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f28dbfe9539 code=0x50000
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.587848:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/15.8.1_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.587988:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/15.8.1_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.588453:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.588520:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.594289:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.594432:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.840539:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.841450:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/15.8.1_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:12 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105112.907820:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/15.8.1_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:15 moonface kernel: [98510.634835] kauditd_printk_skb: 85 callbacks suppressed
Dec  4 10:51:15 moonface kernel: [98510.634840] audit: type=1400 audit(1670169075.594:693): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.opera.opera" name="/run/udev/data/c166:2" pid=139166 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Dec  4 10:51:15 moonface kernel: [98510.636825] audit: type=1400 audit(1670169075.594:694): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.opera.opera" name="/run/udev/data/c166:0" pid=139166 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Dec  4 10:51:15 moonface kernel: [98510.648454] audit: type=1400 audit(1670169075.606:695): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.opera.opera" name="/run/udev/data/c166:1" pid=139166 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Dec  4 10:51:16 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105116.318901:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:16 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105116.365303:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.162112:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.225762:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.272852:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.273443:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.273741:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.275070:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.284146:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface chrome[139166]: [139166:139166:1204/105118.284741:WARNING:chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc(240)] Corruption detected in extension aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa installed at: /home/ramy/snap/opera/210/.config/opera/Extensions/aeblfdkhhhdcdjpifhhbdiojplfjncoa/2.5.0_0, from webstore: 1, corruption reason: 1, should be repaired: 0, extension location: kInternal
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1635.
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface systemd[1]: Stopped Bumblebee C Daemon.
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface systemd[1]: Started Bumblebee C Daemon.
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface bumblebeed[139814]: [98514.434957] [ERROR]No discrete video card found, quitting
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec  4 10:51:18 moonface systemd[1]: bumblebeed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec  4 10:51:23 moonface systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-759c42f721e89be363aac97cfdec28c2ae8fb9d997a61f80123397bc3cf3d05d-runc.ODUmXN.mount: Succeeded.
Dec  4 10:51:23 moonface systemd[3146]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-759c42f721e89be363aac97cfdec28c2ae8fb9d997a61f80123397bc3cf3d05d-runc.ODUmXN.mount: Succeeded.
```

pgrep output (command line): https://pastebin.com/9atwFRAx
pgrep output (activities)  : https://pastebin.com/UbSXEaJS

Comment: I would look at system logs for any related messages.

Comment: could you say more about which log files to look at and what to look for @FedKad

Comment: I would do `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while trying to start `opera` from Activities, to look for any messages related to slow starting of opera. I would try to find out whether starting opera form terminal or Activities will start the _same_ binary: for example you can run `pgrep -a opera` in both cases and compare the command line displayed.

Comment: I would also look for more that one `.desktop` file used to start opera. For example, I would search for `sudo find / -iname "*opera*desktop"` and inspect the contents of each one. Please, note that I am not using / have not used "opera", so my suggestions are limited.

Comment: Thanks @FedKad. I've provided the tail -f output of each method. I'm not sure exactly what to look for though.

Comment: Start by disabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: Disabling Hardware Acceleration helped immensely! However, it doesn't really explain why starting the same program with the same settings is significantly slower with one of the methods. Does starting opera via snap/activities menu somehow try to make use of HWA that opening via command line doesn't?